# “Bring that one by in a couple of days” What does “by” here mean?

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

Conversation:

> Librarian employee: I see you've got some books there. Is that the one you were asked to return?
>
> Student: No, I left it in my dorm room. These are books I need to check out today. **Is it OK if I bring that one *by* in couple of days?**
>
> Librarian employee: Actually, you need to return it today. That is if you want to check out those books today. That's our policy.
>
> Student: Oh, I didn't know that.

What does "by" here mean?

There seems no idiom like "bring by," so I don't really know how to understand what this preposition "by" here means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, **by** has the same meaning as **over here**.

> bring **by**
>   bring **here**
>   begin **over**

It's a shortened colloquial form for

> over here
>   over to you
>   over there

Usually in reference to something which is stationary and often the location of a speaker

> P1: I've got a new book!
>   P2: Bring it **by** when you get a chance so we can all have a look.

or

> When I have some time, I'll stop **by** and say hello.
>   They stopped **by** on their way to the store.