# What brings you by?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of  **"What brings you by?"** is the above sentence commonly used in English conversation?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it.

Comment: I head it in MOM Tv series

Comment: You're supposed to show some effort. But in some case, some idioms are not necessarily in the dictionary. You might want to delete some of your comment as some people might be offended....I didn't dv the question, by the way.

Comment: Please refrain from using swearwords. Don't be rude. Also keep in mind questions need to show effort of research. A simple Google search for "bring someone by" would've told you this question has been asked before: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77139/bring-that-one-by-in-a-couple-of-days-what-does-by-here-mean    Your question could've been closed as a duplicate, but since you have already got your answer, I closed it as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bring somebody by

That is an idiom.

What brings you by? = What caused you to come here, to come by

come by= come to a place, such as an office or house or apartment.